# How to set filter for directories in qfiledialog

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I would like to know is there any way to select only some directories and some files at a time using `QFileDialog` class. Here I set filesfilter but I also need to set folder filter. I have folders which have sort of "extension" in their name (e.g. name.abc,flight.abc etc) and I want only such folders to be selected on the basis of their name

I'm currently using

```
QStringList files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Files & Directories"), QDir::currentPath(),tr("*.doc*.txt") );
```

`tr("*.doc*.txt")`  is my files filter. In the same way I need folders filter with name only `.abc` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use proxy model for the open file dialog. Take a look on the [`QFileDialog::setProxyModel()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel) and documentation of  [the Qt Model/View programming](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-proxy-models.html).