# How to Filter directories in a QFileDialog then set filter for filenames in selected directory

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm trying to create a QFileDialog that will eventually select a file based on a filter, but I want to limit the user to only be able to select from certain directories from a common directory and I haven't had any luck.
I've tried [Filtering directories displayed in a QFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899651/filtering-directories-displayed-in-a-qfiledialog), [qfiledialog - Filtering Folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101100/qfiledialog-filtering-folders) and [How to set filter for directories in qfiledialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744373/how-to-set-filter-for-directories-in-qfiledialog) and haven't had any luck.  I've tried creating a QSortFilterProxyModel but it isn't working as I'm expecting.
Here's what I currently have:

```
class FileFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxModel
{
   protected:
      virtual bool filterAcceptsRow (int row, const QModelIndex &parent) const;
}

bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow (int row, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
   QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index (row, 0, parent);
   QFileSystemModel *fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*> (sourceModel());

   if ((fileModel != NULL) and (fileModel->isDir (index0))
   {
      if (fileModel->fileName(index0).startsWith ("di_"))
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Which is called by:

```
QFileDialog dialog;
FileFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new FileFilterProxyModel;

dialog.setProxyModel (proxyModel);
dialog.setOption (QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog.setDirectory (directoryName);
dialog.setFileMode (QFileDialog::ExistingFile);
dialog.exec ();
```

The result is really confusing me.  When I run the QFileDialog with the FileFilterProxyModel it doesn't show directories (even though there are directories that match the filter).  If I add a qDebug() statement before the check for the fileName it only shows the entries for the path to the specified directory.
What's really strange is that if I make the section where it checks if the directory name starts with "di_" to false and change the other case to true it shows everything but the directories that start with "di_", which I would expect.

I can't figure out how changing the result of the check on the start of the directory name would completely change the directories that are being checked.
Once I get the directories filtered and displayed, I'll then need to filter the subsequent filenames based on a different filter.  Can I use the FileFilterProxyModel for that or do I need to do something different?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @C137 I was able to get only the directories that I wanted displayed and I was able to get the files filtered by adding

```
dialog.SetNameFilter ("<enter filter here>");
```

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the correct code? `filterAcceptsRow` is not getting called at all!

Comment: Also please add `qt` tag, as this is `qt` related question.

Comment: @C137 Yes, since I can change it and it create different results.

Comment: That's weird, nothing seems to be wrong yet nothing is working!!

Comment: @c137 Exactly.  I can't figure out why the files that get pass to `filterAcceptsRow` are different depending on whether the function passes the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I knew where the problem is, first I changed the `FileFilterProxyModel` to become the default filter, like this:

```
bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    if (!index0.isValid()) return false;
    QFileSystemModel *fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
    auto fname = fileModel->fileName(index0);
    bool valid = QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);
    if(fname == "A")valid = false;
    qDebug() << fname << " " << valid;
    return valid;
}
```

And setting dialog directory to `"E:/A/B"`. As directory `A` is invalid, directories `A` and `B` won't be displayed along with all their content.

Now, when I set the filter to this implementation:

```
bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    if (!index0.isValid()) return false;
    QFileSystemModel *fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
    auto fname = fileModel->fileName(index0);
    auto fpath = fileModel->filePath(index0);
    bool valid = fname.startsWith("di_") || fpath == "E:/" || fname == "A" || fname == "B";
    return valid;
}
```

Then directory `B` along side all it's directories that start with `di_` are shown. I think this because all directories in the `path` to these directories are valid.

> What's really strange is that if I make the section where it checks if the directory name starts with "di_" to false and change the other case to true it shows everything but the directories that start with "di_", which I would expect.

Now this is happening because everything in the path to these files/directories is valid, except for directories starting with `di_` that's why they aren't shown.

Finally a complete clean implementation would be:

```
class FileFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
    FileFilterProxyModel(const QString &prefix, const QStringList &path)
        : m_prefix(prefix),
          m_path(path){}
private:
    QString m_prefix;
    QStringList m_path;
protected:
    virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent) const;
};

bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }
    QFileSystemModel *fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
    auto fname = fileModel->fileName(index);
    auto fpath = fileModel->filePath(index);
    if(fileModel->isDir(index))
    {
        // Directory
        if(fpath == m_path[0] || m_path.contains(fname))
        {
            // In path
            return true;
        }
        // Inside the target directory, validate by prefix.
        return fname.startsWith(m_prefix);
    }
    else
    {
        // Filter files the way you want
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which is called by:

```
QFileDialog dialog;
QStringList path;
QString prefix = "di_";
QString directoryName = "E:/A/B";
path << "E:/" << "A" << "B";
dialog.setOption (QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog.setProxyModel(new FileFilterProxyModel("di_", path));
dialog.setDirectory (directoryName);
dialog.setFileMode (QFileDialog::ExistingFile);
dialog.exec ();
```

And now I can sleep in piece :D

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for you help.  
Now I just have to figure out how to filter the files once I get into the directory that I want.

Comment: It wont be hard now, how do you want to filter them? Based on what?

Comment: I'm planning on having it look like a normal QFileDialog::getOpenFileName filename filter but since I'm not using the static function I'm not sure where to specify the filename filter.